# How can I model this parchment?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I'm modeling for nearly a year in Blender but even with that times dedicated I can't find a way to model this parchment. Can someone give me some tips that I can use?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: *pergament* is not an English word, is it? Do you mean *parchment*, the scroll?

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty is that it's a bas-relief. You can try it this way: Create a mesh with edge loops that follow the shape of your parchment:

[image]

Extrude it:

[image]

Move some vertices forward to create the volumes:

[image]

Here is what it gives, of course you'll need to add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and some support edge loops:

[image]